# Why does my regex return empty in the capturing subpattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have written these codes to convert url-like text to hyperlink:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.com(\w*)(\/\S*)?/";
echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="$1://www.$2.com">$1://www.$2.com$3</a>','http://www.abcde.com/index.html');
```

Output is :

```
<a href="http://www..com">http://www..com/index.html</a>
```

But $2 is empty - why is this?

Comment: `$2` references `(\w*)`, which you have placed after `.com` and before the `/`, meaning it will pretty much always be empty.

Comment: You can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/qAjSUu/1) that your group 2 is capturing nothing.

Comment: So how can I get string between www and .com?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/www\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})\.com(\w*\/\S*)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/MJ3A6K/1

Comment: The link I pasted shows how to capture $2.  I don't believe GrumpyCrouton's answer does.

Comment: @NimsPatel I checked what amasmiller is posted. It is different from what GrumpyCrouton is posted.